# Build native ROS nodes using the Android NDK Errors

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,I'm trying to build native ROS nodes using the Android NDK by this tutorial[http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/BuildingNativeROSPackages].
I use **Ubuntu 64bit 14.04LTS** as the host on the VM.
I installed docker by step 1 and step 2 successfully and run ./do_docker.sh cmd,then something goes wrong with this:

```
[ 84%] Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts.dir/src/ts.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_ts.a
[ 84%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 84%] Generating OpenCV Android library project. SDK target: lib_target_sdk_target-NOTFOUND
make[2]: *** [build.xml] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/java/CMakeFiles/opencv_java.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Cross-compiling ROS.
Running catkin_make.
Base path: /opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws
Source space: /opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /opt/roscpp_output/target

Then the cmake comeout some errors :

CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

Installing.

make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
build_cpp.sh /opt/roscpp_output died with error code 2

Creating output/roscpp_android_ndk.tar.gz.

tar: roscpp_android_ndk: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

the CMakeError.log shows like :

CheckIncludeFile.c:1:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2484976465.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2484976465/fast] Error 2

and 


/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:2:8: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec640946834.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec640946834/fast] Error 2


main:CheckFunctionExists.c(.text.main+0x14): error: undefined reference to 'backtrace'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/roscpp_output/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec4272716319] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec4272716319/fast] Error 2
```

I don't know if the cmake errors come from the opencv errors.
Any one Know something about this problem?Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221319/build-native-ros-nodes-using-the-android-ndk-errors/) by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-11-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-11-25**:
It seems like opencv is failing to build, I just cleaned my workspace and started a new do_docker from scratch to see if I can reproduce this issue. I'll let you know.

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-25**:
Thanks a lot !

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-11-26**:
It seems it failed to install correctly the Android SDK inside the container, thus the "SDK target: lib_target_sdk_target-NOTFOUND".

Can you manually install the SDK again inside the container? Here are the instructions: https://gist.github.com/garyservin/34bea53e53690ccc966d

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-26**:
THANKS,I'm trying

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-27**:
I have delete all docker images,and reinstall again,and the problem shows again:"SDK target: lib_target_sdk_target-NOTFOUND"

I have checked the docker images by your advice in ”https://gist.github.com/garyservin/34bea53e53690ccc966d“,and rosndk and android sdk is ok.

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-27**:
then I echo $PATH shows:/usr/lib/ccache:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

echo $ANDROID_HOME  shows:/opt/android-sdk-linux

seems ok?

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-27**:
maybe the step 27 have something wrong,I'm trying

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-27**:
I found some in opencv build:
--   Android:
--     Android ABI:                 armeabi-v7a
--     STL type:                    gnustl_static
--     Native API level:            android-14
--     SDK target:                  android_sdk_target_status-NOTFOUND

do I need install android API 14?

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-28**:
still shows the same problem SDK target: lib_target_sdk_target-NOTFOUND

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-11-30**:
I've upload my rosndk image for now, can you try using it instead of building? https://hub.docker.com/r/garyservin/rosndk/

**Comment by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) on 2015-11-30**:
Thanks so much,I have build successfully by your previous suggestion.It's the Android SDK update errors,I'm writing the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Gary Servin I have build successfully by the following steps:

1.# Check if you have the rosndk image on the list.

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
rosndk              latest              6c374bc001d0        12 hours ago        3.678 GB
```

2.# This will create a container based on the image

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~$ docker run -it rosndk bash
root@58dfb6a0a9f4:/#
```

3.# run ls -l,you should have -rw-r--r--   1 root root 140827643 Jul  2  2014 android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz

```
root@58dfb6a0a9f4:/# ls -l
total 593516
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 466853553 Mar 21  2013 android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 140827643 Jul  2  2014 android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
```

#if not
#run:wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
#and run :tar -xvf android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz -C /opt

4.#run android list and if the android target have been update successfully it should be like this:

```
root@58dfb6a0a9f4:/# android list
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-20"
     Name: Android 4.4W.2
```

#if wrong, there are not any targets list,maybe the same question,then goto step 5.

5.#check if you can update android sdk successfully
(Thanks to the GREETWALL I cannot visit google without VPN).

```
root@58dfb6a0a9f4:/# android update sdk -u -t 2,3,7,8,9,11,13,16,56,57
```

6.#when update successfully,run exit.

```
root@58dfb6a0a9f4:/#exit
```

7.# Commit the latest container to rosndk

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~$docker commit $(docker ps -aq | head -n 1) rosndk
```

8.#delete the wrong build package
#mine is:/home/u64/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android/output/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencvzs

9.just  run ./do_docker.sh again

```
u64@u64-VirtualBox:~/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android$ ./do_docker.sh
```

#when you are success,it shows:

```
summary of what just happened:
  target/      was used to build static libraries for ros software
    include/   contains headers
    lib/       contains static libraries
  roscpp_android_ndk/     is a NDK sub-project that can be imported into an NDK app
  sample_app/  is an example of such an app, a native activity
  sample_app/bin/sample_app-debug.apk  is the built apk, it implements a subscriber and a publisher
  move_base_sample_app/  is an example app that implements the move_base node
  move_base_app/bin/move_base_app-debug.apk  is the built apk for the move_base example
```

GOOD LUCK! THANKS TO GRAY SERVIN'S HELP!

---

Originally posted by [xy1zzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25141/xy1zzz/) with karma: 26 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1